# verifying SSHA512 in php from mysql with dovecot

Tags: php, dovecot

ok so I have been working on a script to register and login script with dovecot and MySQL and PHP but I'm still kinda new to how to decrypt passwords with PHP for ssha512(salted sha512) I've been all over the internet looking up ways of doing this and have come up empty with no real solutions some example

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $trim = substr($row['password'], 9);
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($password, $trim);

            if ($pwdCheck == false) {

                $_SESSION['ERRORS']['wrongpassword'] = $trim ;
                header("Location: ../");
                exit();
            } 
            else if ($pwdCheck == true) {

                session_start();
```

Comment: Why would you want to decrypt passwords? Passwords should be one-way hashed and not retrievable. You've shown us some code using password_verify (), which is the correct approach to verifying a password which has been hashed using password_hash(). I don't know why you're trimming the password beforehand though, that should never be necessary

Comment: If you want to use Dovecat, why do you need to send the user to another page using a `Location` header?

Comment: It's unclear how this relates to dovecot in any way, to be honest. SHA512 is a hashing algorithm anyway btw. Make sure you're clear on the differences between encryption and hashing.

Comment: well how can i verify it in PHP then

Comment: Verify what exactly? If you've got a password you created using password_hash() then - as already mentioned - you can verify it using password_verify(). If that's not what you mean then you need to clarify what exactly you're trying to verify - and why. I smell an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) of some sort, but there's so little detail   or context in your post it's hard to be sure what is really going on.